# Undelete post (untrash)?

Tags: posts, trash

Which function should be used to move post from trash to published pages? 
i.e. is there **`wp_undelete_post`** or something like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is not `wp_undelete_post` but you have other choices:

- [`wp_untrash_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_untrash_post/): when post is trashed, the previous status is stored in `_wp_trash_meta_status` meta field. `wp_untrash_post()` restore trashed posts to previous status whatever it was; for example, private, inherit, publish. I've not tested it but it should work with [a custom post status as well](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_status/).
- [`wp_publish_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_publish_post/): if you want to move from trash to publish status.
- [`wp_update_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/): to move from trash to any other status.

For example, for a given post ID (of any post type, including pages):

```
if( get_post_status( $post_ID ) == "trash" ) {
    wp_update_post( array(
                   'ID'           => $post_ID,
                   'post_status'  => 'publish'
               )
    );
}
```

or:

```
if( get_post_status( $post_ID ) == "trash" ) {
    wp_publish_post( $post_ID );
}
```

or:

```
if( get_post_status( $post_ID ) == "trash" ) {
    wp_untrash_post( $post_ID );
}
```

Comment: For those that came across this, there is a hook called `wp_trash_post` which fires immediately before the post is actually placed in the trash. As of 2017-
07-17 one would think that `wp_untrash_post` would be another hook for the converse purpose. However, it is actually the method to perform the untrashing of a post. The hook instead is called `untrash_post`.

Comment: If you want to untrash a post back to *published*, use both: `wp_untrash_post()` and then `wp_publish_post()`. `wp_publish_post` **WILL** move the post out of the trash and into the publish status, but it **WON'T** remove `_trashed` from the post slug. `wp_untrash_post` will move the post out of the trash into draft status.

Comment: `wp_update_post` worked great for republishing trashed posts

Answer (score 2):

It might be old but it showed up when I was looking for similar problem.
Since WP 2.9.0 there is function called: [wp_untrash_post(int $post_id)](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_untrash_post/)

In my case it worked like a charm.

Answer (score -2):

the solution so far was:

```
$page =get_page_by_path('my-slug', OBJECT, 'page');
if($page && 'trash'==$page->post_status) { wp_update_post(array('ID'=>$page->ID,'post_status'=>'publish')); }
```

Comment: Sorry but you asked about what function to use and I give you the answer: there is no `wp_undelete_post`, use `wp_update_post` or `wp_publish_post`. So I think you should accept my answer as accepted.

Comment: Please note it's quite acceptable for OP to post final working code as an answer.

Comment: @Rast No one could know this answer with the description of the question. Additionally, the OP gets this code because others give him/her the answer. I really think it should be a comment (please, don't think I'm fighting for a few reputation points, I'm not).